# Bind9 transfer to new slave failing

Tags: bind

I built a master bind server using Ubuntu 20.04 and webmin. The master is working normally except for transfers to the slave. The slave is also new Ubuntu 20.04 with webmin. My serials are incrementing on any changes and it is sending a notify to the slave but no transfer occurs. I'm sure I've done something stupid but i'm at a loss and need some help please.

from the slave syslog

```
client @0x7eff48044910 192.40.120.9#33471/key 1: received notify for zone 'telpage.net': TSIG '1': not authoritative
```

Her is my Master named.conf

```
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
key 1 {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    };
server 192.40.120.10 {
    keys {
        1;
        };
    transfer-format one-answer;
    };
controls {
    inet 'master ip' port 953 allow { "master ip"; "slave ip"; } keys { rndc-key; 1; };
    };
key rndc-key {
    algorithm hmac-sha256;
    secret "xxxxxx";
    };
```

named.conf.options

```
//========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    forwarders {
        "forwarder 1";
        "forwarder 2";
        };
    forward first;
    allow-recursion {
        "client ip";
        "client ip";
        };
    allow-query {
        any;
        };
    dnssec-enable yes;
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    auth-nxdomain yes;
};
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "telpage.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/telpage.net.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "amandajoneslaw.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/amandajoneslaw.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "brunswickco.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/brunswickco.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "buckwaterplantation.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/buckwaterplantation.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "chapmanlumber.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/chapmanlumber.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "consciencestream.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/consciencestream.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "dickensconstruction.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/dickensconstruction.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "elliottsadler.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/elliottsadler.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "emporiaciviccenter.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporiaciviccenter.org.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "emporiamedical.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporiamedical.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "emporianews.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporianews.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "flyemv.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/flyemv.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "flyemv.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/flyemv.org.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "franklinbraid.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/franklinbraid.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "goodearthpeanuts.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/goodearthpeanuts.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "greensvillecountyva.gov" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/greensvillecountyva.gov.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "jarrattfire.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jarrattfire.org.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "jlwalston.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jlwalston.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "jrallpc.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jrallpc.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "lakegastonassoc.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lakegastonassoc.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "lastday.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lastday.net.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "lgaston.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lgaston.org.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "midatlanticinfosec.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/midatlanticinfosec.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "midatlantictower.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/midatlantictower.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "modsbyus.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/modsbyus.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "motorolaradio.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/motorolaradio.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "naynaysartbox.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/naynaysartbox.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "omnitowers.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/omnitowers.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "osg-armor.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/osg-armor.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "sadlerbrosoil.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/sadlerbrosoil.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "sadlerfanclub.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/sadlerfanclub.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "southsideccjb.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/southsideccjb.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "telpage.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/telpage.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "thevirginiapeanutfestival.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/thevirginiapeanutfestival.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "virginiacarolina.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/virginiacarolina.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "whitman-properties.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/whitman-properties.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "wrobinsonlaw.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/wrobinsonlaw.com.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "ymcaofeg.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/ymcaofeg.org.hosts";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    notify yes;
    };
```

named.conf.default-zones

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/usr/share/dns/root.hints";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "slave ip";
        };
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "slave ip";
        };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "slave ip";
        };
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
    also-notify {
        "slave ip";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "slave ip";
        };
};
```

On the slave:

named.conf

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the 
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize 
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
key rndc-key {
    algorithm hmac-sha256;
    secret "xxxxxxx";
    };
controls {
    inet "slave ip" port 953 allow { "slave ip"; "master ip"; } keys { rndc-key; 1; };
    };
server "master ip" {
    keys {
        1;
        };
    };
key 1 {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "xxxxxxxx";
    };
logging {
    channel bind_log {
        null;
        };
    };
```

named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    transfer-source "master ip";
    allow-query {
        any;
        };
    forwarders {
        "forwarder 1";
        "forwarder 2";
        };
    allow-transfer {
        "master ip";
        };
    transfer-format one-answer;
};
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "telpage.net" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/telpage.net.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "amandajoneslaw.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/amandajoneslaw.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "brunswickco.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/brunswickco.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "buckwaterplantation.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/buckwaterplantation.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "chapmanlumber.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/chapmanlumber.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "consciencestream.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/consciencestream.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "dickensconstruction.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/dickensconstruction.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "elliottsadler.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/elliottsadler.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "emporiaciviccenter.org" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporiaciviccenter.org.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "emporiamedical.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporiamedical.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "emporianews.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/emporianews.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "flyemv.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/flyemv.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "flyemv.org" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/flyemv.org.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "franklinbraid.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/franklinbraid.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "goodearthpeanuts.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/goodearthpeanuts.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "greensvillecountyva.gov" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/greensvillecountyva.gov.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "jarrattfire.org" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jarrattfire.org.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "jlwalston.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jlwalston.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "jrallpc.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/jrallpc.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "lakegastonassoc.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lakegastonassoc.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "lastday.net" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lastday.net.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "lgaston.org" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/lgaston.org.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "midatlanticinfosec.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/midatlanticinfosec.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "midatlantictower.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/midatlantictower.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "modsbyus.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/modsbyus.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "motorolaradio.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/motorolaradio.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "naynaysartbox.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/naynaysartbox.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "omnitowers.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/omnitowers.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "osg-armor.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/osg-armor.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "sadlerbrosoil.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/sadlerbrosoil.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "sadlerfanclub.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/sadlerfanclub.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "southsideccjb.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/southsideccjb.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "telpage.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/telpage.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "thevirginiapeanutfestival.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/thevirginiapeanutfestival.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "virginiacarolina.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/virginiacarolina.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "whitman-properties.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/whitman-properties.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "wrobinsonlaw.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/wrobinsonlaw.com.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
zone "ymcaofeg.org" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/ymcaofeg.org.hosts";
    masters {
        <master ip>;
    };
    };
```

named.conf.default-zones

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/usr/share/dns/root.hints";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912


zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type slave;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

Comment: I believe you not only have to specify the master IP address but also which key to use for that master.

Comment: The zone files are not being created. and the zones don't show in webmin interface after adding them to named.conf.local. I have been at this for a week trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any slave zones on your slave server in `named.conf.local` (the file is empty).

You need:

```
zone "telpage.net" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/lib/bind/telpage.net.hosts.slave";
    masters {
        <ip_of_master>;
    };
    };
```

and so on for remaining zones you wish to host there.

See bind ARM for slave zone definition (https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.11.13/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#zone_statement_grammar).

Comment: I did that and the zones didnt populate in webmin, and they still didn't update when a change was made on the server. Also, when I did that the file wasn't created in /var/lib/bind after applying and restarting bind. I will do this again and let you know the results

Comment: After adding the slave zones to named.local I get this error.     Nov  5 21:48:20 ns2 named[15057]: client @0x7f5750048c20 192.40.120.9#55433/key 1: received notify for zone 'omnitowers.com': TSIG '1'
Nov  5 21:48:20 ns2 named[15057]: zone omnitowers.com/IN: notify from 192.40.120.9#55433: no serial

Comment: I edited my origonal post with the updated named.conf.local on the slave.

Comment: Which error did you get after adding this zone information on the slave? Please update your question once more.